# C++ command line args (file) not found?

Tags: c++, file, command-line, arguments

I have the following main method:

```
int main(string argf)
{

ifstream exprFile(argf);
string inExpr;
if (exprFile.is_open())
{
while ( getline(exprFile,inExpr) )
{
    //do stuff
}
exprFile.close();
}
else cout << "Unable to open file"; 

system("pause"); // to wait for user input; allows the user to see what was printed before the window closes
return 0;
}
```

I have run this program from the command line using the following:

- "C:\Complete Filepath\Project2.exe" "C:\Differnt Filepath\args.txt"
- C:\Complete Filepath\Project2.exe C:\Differnt Filepath\args.txt
- "C:\Complete Filepath\Project2.exe" "args.txt"
- C:\Complete Filepath\Project2.exe args.txt

The last two with args.txt being in the same directory as the executable. All four gave the "Unable to open file" result. Attemping to print the `argf` value before doing anything with it yielded nothing at all. A completely blank print statement.

I then went into the Visual Studio 2010 options and added all variations of the `args.txt` file under the arguments section there with the file in different locations as well and nothing works.

What am I doing wrong?

How are you supposed to open a file passed as an argument on the command line?

Comment: This is not a valid declaration of `main()`.  See [What should `main()` return in C and C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c/) for a detailed discussion of what is allowed and what is not allowed as the definition of `main()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
```

This is correct way to get argument from `main`.

`argc` is number of arguments. `argv` is argument list.

Actual argument will start with `index = 1.` Value at `index 0` will be always program name.

In your example,

> "C:\Complete Filepath\Project2.exe" "C:\Differnt Filepath\args.txt"

```
argc = 2
argv[0] = "Project2.exe" 
argv[1] = "C:\Differnt Filepath\args.txt"
```

Comment: what is `int argc` in this case? What use do I have for an integer? And I'm assuming the `argv[]` is the char array (string) file location?

Comment: `argc` is the number of arguments; `argv` is a pointer to an array of pointers, each of which points to a plain-old-char-array null-terminated string.  `argv[argc] == 0` so you can also detect the end of the arguments by looking at the pointers.

Comment: Thank you guys. I guess I was looking in the wrong place. I thought my problem was with the command line calling procedure not the argument passing. I see this is quite well covered elsewhere as well.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for information on _argv[argc] ==0_ check.

Answer (score 0):

Yay, code!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   ifstream exprFile;
   string inExpr;
   for( int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {  // 0 is the program name
      exprFile.open(argv[i]);
      if (exprFile.is_open()) {
         while ( getline(exprFile,inExpr) ) {
            cout << "Doing stuff on line: " << inExpr << "\n";
         }
         exprFile.close();
      }
      else cout << "Unable to open file " << argv[i];
   }
}
```